# CollectionView Custom cell Label Disappears on Scroll

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell

I have a custom cell for my collectionview and one of the labels in the cell disappears when I scroll down and back up to the cell again.

Here is my `cellForItemAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
if collectionView == productCollectionView {
if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Identifiers.ProductCell, for: indexPath) as? ProductCell {

if cartProducts.contains(products[indexPath.item]) {
//this is the product
var product = products[indexPath.item]
//get the index from cartProducts
let index = cartProducts.firstIndex(of: product)

//Get the cartcount and update the product
let cartCount: Int = cartProducts[index!].cartCount
product.cartCount = cartCount
products[indexPath.item] = product

//now set the updated product for cell.product
cell.product = products[indexPath.item]
cell.delegate = self
return cell

} else {
cell.product = products[indexPath.item]
cell.delegate = self
return cell
}

} else 
if collectionView == categoryCollectionView{
//...this is another collection and not the collectionView that I have problem with
return cell
}

return UICollectionViewCell()
}
}
```

And here is what I have in y custom cell for the label that is disappearing when I scroll down and back up to the cell:

```
class ProductCell: UICollectionViewCell {
var product: Product!
    {
        didSet {
            commonUIUpdate()
        }
    }

func commonUIUpdate() {
//set the price per amount and its unit
        if product.pricePerAmountExist == true {
            pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = false
            if let PricePerAmount = formatter.string(from: Double(product.pricePerAmount)/100 as NSNumber) {
                let PricePerAmountVoume = Float(String(Double(product.pricePerAmountVolume)/100))?.clean ?? ""

                pricePerAmountLbl.text = "\(PricePerAmount)/\(String(describing: PricePerAmountVoume))\(product.pricePerAmountUnit)"
            }
        } else
            if product.pricePerAmountExist == false {
                pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = true
        }
}
}
```

I have the label `pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden` set to true and false when needed but still I dont understand why its disappearing. When I dont set the hidden status for the label in the custom cell the content of the label gets repeated in all cell which is not right either.

**Edit:**

I added the following to the cell but still no success the problem is still there

```
else if product.pricePerAmountExist == false {
    pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = true
} else {
   pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with my code! The error was happening in storyboard. My label was stored in a stackview and that stackview was stored in another  stackview; when I was scrolling and the label would go hidden the stackview height would have gone to zero and it stayed at zero even though I unhide the label.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling all cases. Your label stays hidden because it was set hidden in the previous cell. You might want to alter you code to cover for the missing case. Hope it helps:

```
else if product.pricePerAmountExist == false {
    pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = true
} else {
   pricePerAmountLbl.isHidden = false
   pricePerAmountLbl.text = "This case was not handled before"
}
```

Comment: I did that too but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: That is unfortunate. Could you check the code you posted above for the method `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell` It looks like it is missing the return of the UICollectionViewCell in case the following is not true: `if collectionView == productCollectionView`

Comment: yeah I dont see any problem there. I have another collection there which I have no problem with. Just edited my post including that too just in case